# Bootstrap 4 – How to display items in a row when navbar is collapsed?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to display some items next to each other when the window is collapsed in the navbar. Currently, it displays the items in a column like this: [Navbar collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOF0z.png). I want the image next to the username instead.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav"
  aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>


<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">


      <ul class="ml-auto navbar-nav border border-primary rounded" style="background:blue">

        <li class=" nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Hi, Shadow <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li id="something1" class="mt-auto mb-auto nav-item">
          <img id="something" src="images/space_stars_blue_free_wallpaper.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded-circle "
            alt="..." width="50" height="50">
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please share the working version of that on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the flex-row class to the `navbar-nav`...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="ml-auto navbar-nav border border-primary rounded flex-row" style="background:blue">
            <li class=" nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Hi, Shadow <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li id="something1" class="mt-auto mb-auto nav-item">
                <img id="something" src="//placehold.it/50" class="img-fluid rounded-circle ml-1" alt="..." width="50" height="50">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/U0dP6MM9WJ

Answer (score 1):

Making the **navbar-nav** and **navbar list items** to `display: inline-block` will do what you want:

```
.navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Bootstrap 4, they have a inline list class for the unordered list and it's list items. It would look something like this:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li class="list-inline-item">Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li class="list-inline-item">Phasellus iaculis</li>
  <li class="list-inline-item">Nulla volutpat</li>
</ul>
```

Here is the link to check out Bootstraps official documentation on it: 
http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/typography/#inline